# Matlab: Monte Carlo Value at Risk - Rolling calculation (very basic)

Tags: matlab, montecarlo

I have a stock index for which I need to compute the VaR using a MC simulation with the geometric brownian motion model as the stochastic process. This is my first try, disregarding the gbm, just to get familiar with the program and syntax:

```
x=logreturn; %file with 500 returns
mu=mean(x),
sigma=sigma(x),
rand=normrnd(mu,sigma,2000,1); %random normal distr numbers
VaR=quantile(rand,0.05); %95 percent VaR
VaR=-0.045
```

It's very basic and calculates the VaR only for one day, but I need to calculate the VaR for the first 250 days with a 250-day rolling window for mu and sigma.

Based on Ahmed's comment I tried to implement arrayfun and cellfun for the full function:

```
x=logreturn;
mu=movmean(x,250); 
sigma=movstd(x,250); 
mydata = normrnd(0,1,1,20000)
muforsample=arrayfun(@(v) mu*250, mu, 'un', false);
sigmaforsample=arrayfun(@(v) sigma*sqrt(250), sigma, 'un', false);
k=arrayfun(@(v) muforsample-(sigmaforsample.^2)/2, muforsample, sigmaforsample, 'un', false); %this line is faulty and gives an error message (too many input arguments)
t=1/504;
sqrtt=sqrt(t);
gbm=k*t+sigmaforsample*sqrtt; %didnt't try to fix this since I don't have a k
VaR=quantile(gbm, 0.05) %unchanged, needs cellfun too, right?
```

For k I need basically a value based on the corresponding muforsample and sigmaforsample so that I can calculate the gbm

Comment: Wow, `movmean` and `movstd` and friends look cool! Upgrading to 2016a to check them out.

Comment: ‘But now normrnd doesn't work anymore.’ Can you show the `normrnd` command that you tried? `mu` and `sigma` (from `movmean` and `movstd`) are now vectors the same size as `x`, so a single call to `normrnd(mu, sigma, ...)` can only return an array the same size as `mu` and `sigma`. If you want to generate 2000 draws from each sample in `mu`, you need [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html): `r = arrayfun(@(m, s) normrnd(m, s, 2000, 1), mu, sigma, 'un', false)`, which will give you a cell array. Then `VaR = cellfun(@(v) quantile(v, 0.05), r)` should do the trick.

Comment: `normrnd(mu,sigma,2000,1)` is what I used, so the same command as in the 1-day calculation. Thank you for your answer, I'll try that!

Comment: @AhmedFasih your solution works, thank you very much! I tried to follow your solution for the gbm, with multiple arrayfuns. Could you maybe take a look at it? I'm way too untalented for coding :(

Comment: I don’t think your `muforsample` is correct—`arrayfun` takes a function and then one or more arrays (and finally if necessary `..., 'un', 0` which is short for [`'uniformOutput', 0`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html#namevaluepairarguments)) and applies that function to each element of the array(s). Here’s documentation on [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: So `muforsample = arrayfun(@(v) mu*250, mu, 'un', false)` is equivalent to `muforsample = cell(size(mu)); for i=1:numel(mu); muforsample{i} = mu*250; end`. This means each element in the `muforsample` cell array is `250*mu`. I don’t think this is what you want?

Comment: If you can describe the GBM algorithm in pseudocode, that’d help see what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Hi @AhmedFasih, thank you very much, again. I pretty much gave up on arrayfun and cellfun and tried for loops. I posted my solution (which works, surprisingly) as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `for` loop is definitely easier than `cellfun` and `arrayfun`. Here's my solution:

```
% file with log returns until t(n-1)
x = logreturns;

t = 1/250;

% mu and sigma based on 250 returns, moving window
mu = movmean(x,250);
sigma = movstd(x,250);

% k for every cell
k = zeros(size(mu));
for i = 1:length(mu);
    k(i) = mu(i)*250 - (((sigma(i)*sqrt(250)).^2)/2);
end

% 0.99 or 0.95 VaR, quantiles based on 500,000 values
VaR = zeros(size(mu));
for j = 1:length(mu)
    VaR(j) = quantile(normrnd(0,1,1,500000) * sqrt(t) * ...
    (sigma(j) * sqrt(250)) + k(j) * t, 0.01);
end
```

This is the formula by the way:

[image]